# UV Unwrap faces distorted even after using seams to separate them. v2.81

Tags: uv

I have Blender 2.81.  I'm trying to UV unwrap a model but my faces are distorted, see image.  Why are they being distorted?  I thought completely isolating a face with seams would allow it to UV unwrap as its own island with the original shape.
Thanks. [image: UV Unwrap face distorted]